# C# Regex Rreplace between delimiters

Tags: regex

I want to replace all characters between tags 11= and ~ with a another set. Example 11=1234~ should be replaced by 11=56789~. The first delimiter should be word bounded, meaning, 111= should not be a match

Answer (score 1):

Well you have already answered your question :

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(?<=\b11=).*?(?=~)", "56789");
```

This is .NET, you can translate it to other flavors/engines.

**Explanation:**

```
@"
(?<=      # Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
   \b        # Assert position at a word boundary
   11=       # Match the characters “11=” literally
)
.         # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *?        # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
(?=       # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   ~         # Match the character “~” literally
)
"
```

Comment: If I am 'earth' in reg expressions, the answerer is 'stars'! Thanks.

Comment: @S.Sundararajan Thanks but that is actually pretty basic. I would suggest reading a good tutorial e.g. http://www.regular-expressions.info/